# iPhone set some time delay 

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, ios4, uipickerview

HI;

In my iPhone App in UipickerView can I move picker Values up or down Programmatically

To add effect of an animation like picker is moving itself only
for that

```
[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; 

----    ---
//here I need Some time delay

[picker selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

How can I give some time delay between execution of this two statements

Please help and Suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add some delay, you could use :

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
```

But this will block your application, so it can be better to use a timer :

```
//In your method :
[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; 

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(animatePickerTimer:) userInfo:picker repeats:NO];


//In the same class


-(void)animatePickerTimer:(NSTimer *)timer;
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(animatePicker:) withObject:(UIPickerView *)timer.userInfo waitUntilDone:NO];

    //Not sure if this is required, since the timer does not repeat
    [timer invalidate];
}

-(void)animatePicker:(UIPickerView *)picker
{
[picker selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

This should be performed on main thread, since UIKit is not thread safe

Comment: Thanks. this is working.                                  Can I perform the selection of "selectRow" for random value  means in my App I want to stop picker Animation at random point every time. values will be from my Array only but index will be dufferent

Comment: Sure, you just need to change the "3" in selectRow:3. Let's say you have an array of NSNumbers *myArray, you can fetch a random number : int randIndex = arc4random() % [myArray count]; and then use [picker selectRow:[[myArray objectAtIndex:randIndex] intValue] inComponent:0 animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

You mean this method

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Thanks fr reply.Yes similar to this on button click :[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];  but here I want to give some time delay between changing the "Selectedraw" value si it will loke like an Animation

Comment: if you put YES for the last value(animated:) then it will look like an animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the second selection after a delay through `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` method

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

[self.pickerView selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:NO];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It worked for me like a charm!

I thought this will never gonna work, but it is pretty fine!